# Comma's priority in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to solve this problem.
A = {3,14}

What is the number of elements in this set?

I am thinking about the answer is 1. Because the priority of comma's mathematical decimal function is more than math's grammar in my opinion. I inspired computer languages' mechanism.

If there is a wrong about this message, please report it to me. I'm newbie.

Edit: That was a question in exam in Turkey. In our country (Turkey) we are using comma with decimals in general. So there may be a trick.

Comment: I think it really depends on whether the book uses commas as separators or decimal points.

Comment: I doubt there's a better answer to this question than "It depends..."

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I edited first message to explain special situation about my question. I'm still not sure about the answer. @MichealHoppe

Answer (score 1):

Priority of mathematical operators has nothing to do with this. If the language the book is written in uses . as decimal separator, then $A$ contains two elements. If it uses , as decimal separator, then it depends on how the book denotes a set; from what I've seen, that would still be a comma, but followed by whitespace. So in that case, the answer is "it depends".

Answer (score 0):

An answer appears here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Hindu.E2.80.93Arabic_numeral_system
So if you live in Zimbabwe the answer is 2, would you live in Kirgistan the answer was 1.

Comment: It just says that we use comma or a point to specify a decimal. Anyway thank you for your answer. I forgot to say this special situation in my question. So that was my fault.

Answer (score 0):

You have written {3,14} with no space. If that is correct, then the set has one element. If the original was {3, 14} (note the space!), then the set has two elements.